# Hibernate-Search cause NoClassDefFound

Tags: hibernate, maven, hibernate-search

I'm trying to use Hibernate-Search with Hibernate-core 5.2.6, so i putted this in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

But when i use this dependency i got NoClassDefFoundError in my EntityManagerProducer, i have not ideia why this happens. If i remove this dependency everthing works fine.

**Edit: This is my EntityManagerProducer.**

```
import org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.api.entitymanager.PersistenceUnitName;
import org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.api.transaction.TransactionScoped;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Disposes;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class EntityManagerProducer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("generalPU");

    @Produces
    @TransactionScoped
    // is a bit better than @RequestScoped because it won't allow perform injection outside transaction context
    public EntityManager createEntityManager() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void close(@Disposes EntityManager em) {
        if (em.isOpen()) {
            em.close();
        }
    }


    public EntityManagerFactory getEmf() {
        return emf;
    }


    public void setEmf(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.emf = emf;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you show your EntityManagerProducer?

Comment: Sure, i edited my post with this content.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at their repo and it turns out you need hibernate 5.0.11 Final for Hibernate Search 5.5.6 [Look here if you need](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/hibernate/hibernate-search-parent/5.5.6.Final/hibernate-search-parent-5.5.6.Final.pom)

So i think your problem is incompatible version. Try to downgrade your hibernate version and let me know. :)

Comment: Exactly. Note that Hibernate Search 5.7 aims at supporting Hibernate ORM 5.2, but the latest released version so far (5.7.0.Beta2) only supports it up to 5.2.2.The next release should support ORM 5.2.6. See https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2380